# Check data has already been fetched for react-redux in action, reducer or component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Quite a simple question but I'm new to Redux so a bit unsure of the best practice. If I want to check whether some data has been fetched already, should I put that check inside the action, reducer, component, or somewhere else (eg, middleware)?

I'd like the most flexibility without having to reuse the same checks every time I'm requesting data from a component.

Here's a simplified version of my setup as it stands... thanks in advance!

```
// Action
export const fetchData = () => (dispatch) => {
  const data = { ...someData };
  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED', data: data });
};

// Reducer
export const DataReducer = (state = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  data: [],
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD': {
      return { ...state, data: [...state.data, action.data] };
    }
    case 'FETCH_DATA_START': {
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    }
    case 'FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED': {
      return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, data: action.data };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

// React component
export class Display extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    if (!this.props.data.fetched && !this.props.data.fetching) {
      this.props.dispatch(fetchData());
    }
  }
  render () {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Your version looks good. If you have to check the presence of the same data in different components, then try to find a common parent if possible to make this check. But otherwise you version looks completely fine.

Comment: Thanks both @KornholioBeavis and @panther! The answer below suggests putting it into the action, any reason against that in your collective opinion?

Comment: You still have to include some kind of logic inside your component to actually tell it what to render. e.g . Loader if loading, error if error etc

Comment: actions dispatch simple objects to your reducers to update your state, which again tell your component what they should render. This is my 50cents on the matter

Answer (score 2):

It will smell if you'll put this kind of conditional logic inside your `reducers`, because `reducers` are supposed to have no side-effects.

**I would recommend to keep that logic inside `fetchData` method**. At least that is where I put it in my apps. It will eliminate the need for the checks if data is fetched inside your `Component`. Not only your `Component` will be simpler, but it also will let you minimize changes in future if you'll decide to change fetching conditions, e.g. re-fetching if data is outdated.

If you'll see that you are repeating the same logic (i.e. check if not fetched, then fetch) across different fetching actions then it may worth to place it in some kind `middleware`, but I doubt it will worth it. Probably, introducing fetch action factory will be cleaner solution.

Comment: There are examples of this on the redux-thunk page at https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk - For example you see it do: return Promise.resolve(); when it doesn't want to dispatch an actual action.

Answer (score 1):

Few points

Actions tell your application what has happened. **Actions answer the question what has happened but doesnt specify how the application's state changes in response**.

The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state, thats all it does. Something a reducer should never do is e.g. **to perform side effects like API calls**

I think one best practice and also something that changed the way I code react is understanding Container Components. Currently your component is responsible for both fetching data and presenting it. This is "Ok" but you miss out on React's key benefits. Composability. If you add a lot of data logic in your component, you miss out on the possibility to reuse the component somewhere else.

Small example, not tested

```
//container.js
import Component from 'component.js';
import { fetchData } from './actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => {
      dispatch(fetchData())
        .then((data) => //Do something else
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);

//component.js
const RenderComponent = props =>
  <ul>
    {this.props.data.map(e => (
      <li>{e.somethinghere}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

So to answer your question: **Add the data fetching logic into your container component**

Comment: I get ya. Not sure what the code sample really represents though?

Comment: It basically represents a container component wrapping your component. Please see that the data fetching logic now lives in the container and is provided down to the wrapped component

Comment: Okay, but then there are situations all around an application where you'd want the data, putting the fetches into a container seems to not really add anything of use imo if they're dotted around all over the place.